# when i execute this script work for some seconds then internal error 500 occurs

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

```
<?php
'require 'facebook.php';
include 'config.php';
//database connect
@mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
//Create facebook application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fb_app_id,
  'secret' => $fb_secret
));`$output = '';

   //get users and try liking
  $result = mysql_query("
      SELECT
         *
      FROM
         Likers 
   ");
`

    if($result){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
         $m = $row['access_token'];
         $facebook->setAccessToken ($m);
         $id = trim($_POST ['postid']);
      try {
         $facebook->api("/".$id."/comments",'post',array('message' => $comment));
      }
      catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $output .= "<p>'". $row['name'] . "' failed to like.</p>";
         }
}
}
?>
```

When script execution Start Work fine for 10 or 15 seconds and perform output
but after sometime give 500 internal  server error

I guess it is time limit issue but I used both time interval and time limit codes nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

It can´t work at all like that, fix your errors. For example:

```
'require 'facebook.php'; (remove that sign at the beginning)
`$output = ''; put this in a new line and remove that sign at the beginning)
$comment is not defined
```

Also, you should use PDO, not mysql_connect. Check out the PHP docs for that.

Btw, it looks like you want to create some kind of "Autoliker" or "Autocommenter". Keep in mind that this is not allowed on Facebook (obviously).